# ibm_db - TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined in electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, db2, odbc

I need to get some data from db2 inside my electron vue app.
I'm on a windows 11 system with node 16 that is installed as a dev dependency to avoid problems with vue-electron-builder plugin, I've tried to use `node-ibm_db` but I will always get this error after importing the library in the main process of electron

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at Function.getFileName (webpack:///./node_modules/bindings/bindings.js?:178:16)
    at bindings (webpack:///./node_modules/bindings/bindings.js?:82:48)
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/ibm_db/lib/odbc.js?:57:86)
    at Object../node_modules/ibm_db/lib/odbc.js (C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\tool\dist_electron\index.js:1125:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\tool\dist_electron\index.js:20:30)
    at eval (webpack:///./src/background.js?:12:64)
    at Module../src/background.js (C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\tool\dist_electron\index.js:3121:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\tool\dist_electron\index.js:20:30)
    at eval (webpack:///multi_./src/background.js?:1:18)
    at Object.0 (C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\tool\dist_electron\index.js:3144:1)
```

node integration is disabled, but I don't think this is the problem? Is there any way to make the library work?I've readed on the documentation that I need to set an system variable and I've done it using the set command in the cdm prompt of windows, but this didn't helped. How I can correctly setup the library?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be happening in a DB operation, it looks like the problem is in WebPack require.

Comment: I'm not using require but import sinche the vue-electron-builder plugin will scaffold the background.js file using import instead of require. At the moment my vue front-end is managed from vite, but probably as you've noticed, webpack is used when the npm run electron:serve command is called. Any solution?